# Diferença entre varchar2 e nvarchar2

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

No Oracle, existem dois tipos de dados que posso usar para representar textos, o `varchar2` e o `nvarchar2`.

Qual a diferença entre esses dois tipos de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nvarchar2` armazena os caracteres como unicode e o encode deve ser AL16UTF16 ou UTF8.

`varchar2` armazena os caracteres conforme outros encondes além dos fornecidos por `nvarchar2`.

[nvarchar2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i14946)

[varchar2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1835)